# Can GNU ld be instructed to print which .o files are needed during a link?

Tags: c++, ld, avr, avr-gcc

*A little background:* I'm trying to build an AVR binary for an embedded sensor system, and I'm running close to my size limit. I use a few external libraries to help me, but they are rather large when compiled into one object per library. I want to pull these into smaller objects so only the functionality I need is linked into my program. I've already managed to drop the binary size by 2k by splitting up a large library.

It would help a lot to know which objects are being used at each stage of the game so I can split them more efficiently. Is there a way to make `ld` print which objects it's linking?

Comment: AFAIK ld should only link in functions that are actually usef. Sidenote: are you using -Os optimization?

Comment: Yes, right now it's turned all the way up to -O3. I don't see why ld would pull in additional code, but when I split one of the larger libraries up it reduced the binary size significantly.

Comment: Use `nm -a` on the resulting executable file. This will list debugging symbols, including names of the *source* files.

Comment: Fantastic, that is extremely useful. Thanks for the tip! EDIT: It also seems to work with debugging symbols turned off, so I don't have to build separate binaries.

Comment: Don't use `-O3`. Use `-Os`. The first is for performance, the second is for size.

Comment: Ah, that's even better! Dropped 10k off the binary size. That gives me all the room I need. Thank you!

Comment: You may want to have a look at gcc's `-ffunction-sections` flag in combination with `-Wl,--gc-sections` for the linker. This should allow the linker to remove unused funtions from the binary.

Comment: @n.m.: if there are debugging symbols, then stripping those might be the first and best way to considerably reduce the size of the binary.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the *object* level, but I believe you might be able to tackle this on the *symbol* level using `CFLAGS="-fdata-sections -ffunction-sections"` and `LDFLAGS="-Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--print-gc-sections"`. This should get rid of the code for all unreferenced symbols, and display the removed symbols to you as well which might be useful if for some reason you decide to go back to the object file level and want to identify object files only containing removed symbols.

To be more precise, the compiler flags I quoted will ask the compiler to place each function or global variable in a section for itself, and the `--gc-sections` linker flag will then remove all the sections which have not been used. It might be that each object file contains its own sections, even if the functions therein all share a single section. In that case the linker flag alone should do what you ask for: eliminate whole objects which are not used. The gcc manual states that the compiler flags will increase the object size, and although I hope that the final executable should not be affected by this, I don't know for sure, so you should give the `LDFLAGS="-Wl,--gc-sections` by itself a try in any case.

The listed option names might be useful keywords to search on stackoverflow for other suggestions on how to reduce the size of the binary. `gc-sections` e.g. yields 62 matches at the moment.