# Can I have linker tell me which object files are used from a statically linked library

Tags: gcc, linker, static-libraries, ld

When building a binary, I'm statically linking against a library that we build from scratch.  I'd like to know which particular object files are being linked against from the static library.  Is there a way to get the linker to tell me this?

I am using GNU ld, the one associated with the gcc 4.8 compiler.

---

### Update

Using [Can GNU ld be instructed to print which .o files are needed during a link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10577512/can-gnu-ld-be-instructed-to-print-which-o-files-are-needed-during-a-link#comment13697781_10577512), I got what I needed via `nm` on the built binary.  But it would still be interesting to know whether this can be derived via linker output.